How would I make it so something happens only once if a key is pressed down and not continuously until I stop holding it?

if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x * 2, rb.velocity.y * 2);

I don't know how to make it so,
using GetKey simply made it always happen when held down, GetKeyDown / GetKeyUp just made it not happen at all even when the key is pressed.
someone help

Please add a tag specifying the UI framework you use (WPF, WinForms, Xamarin, UWP, ASP.NET, MAUI, Unity, ...)

@KlausGütter thanks, done, also me not specifying the UI framework doesn't stop you from helping out

where is this code ? if its not in update then there is a chance that getkeydown wont happen..

@BugFinder it is in update, I did not leave it outside of a function

well that 1 if statement is fine, it willl work if in update and not inside any other if statement, if there is anything else going on it could cause this not to get run.. but the issue is not here.

Declare a flag:
bool jumping;

Then:
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && !jumping)
{
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x * 2, rb.velocity.y * 2);
    jumping = true;
}
if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space) && jumping)
{
    jumping = false;
}

But I honestly recommend to get along with new Input System (found in package manager). It may seem overwhelmingly complicated at first, but is very straightforward and became the industry standard today.
For example, in that new system you can subscribe to the input action start and end events, this will eliminate the need to use additional flags. There is tons of tutorials on that system on YouTube.
